# How to throw a 502 to nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a nginx/nodejs stack.

My nginx is configured to serve a static 502 error page when my nodejs process is down.

Now, i want to have my nodejs to run normally, and occasionally throws a 502 to nginx, to trigger the static 502 page on some user requests. How do i do that?

I tried to throw some errors in my node process without catching them, but it results in the error stack being passed directly to the client browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your proxy config:

```
 proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

As per [the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors):

> Determines whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive. Default off